# Filter letters from string replacing symbols for blanks spaces and letters lowercase

Tags: haskell, filter, words, letter

## Example: `"Paul's! Come There"`

## GetOutput: `"paul s  come there"`

```
 myFilter :: String -> String
 myFilter str = unwords . filter (not . null) . map (
                              map toLower . filter  isLetter
                              ) . words $ str
```

How can I filter the letters into lowerCase and at the same time replace all non-word symbols with blanks?

Comment: Here's a hint: `if isLetter x then ... else ...`

Comment: yes but in this form: 
     map $ (\c -> if not isLetter c then ' ' else c)
output:
     Couldn't match expected type ‘Char -> Bool’ with actual type ‘Bool’
    The function ‘not’ is applied to two arguments,
    but its type ‘Bool -> Bool’ has only one
    In the expression: not isLetter c
    In the expression: if not isLetter c then ' ' else c

Comment: That's the idea. To get the syntax correct that would be `map (\c -> if not (isLetter c) then ' ' else c)`  (note the parenthesis) which is the same as `map (\c -> if isLetter c then c else ' ')`

Comment: @Cirdec Put it in an answer!

Answer (score 1):

@Cirdec That's the idea. To get the syntax correct that would be map 
     `(\c -> if not (isLetter c) then ' ' else c)` (note the parenthesis) which is   the same as `map (\c -> if isLetter c then c else ' ')`